# My editor doesn't like `asserts x is y` in function signature

Tags: typescript, webstorm

The [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) says that you can have a function signature like

```js
function assertIsString(val: any): asserts val is string {...
```

I've updated my TypeScript package to the latest and my editor, WebStorm, is giving me problems with this:

```js
function forceTypeNarrow<TWanted>(value: any): asserts value is TWanted {}
```

It's telling me it needs a semicolon after `asserts`, after `value`, after `is` and after `TWanted`.

Is it an issue with TSLint?

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-internal-module": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unsafe-finally": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "double"
    ],
    "semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "variable-name": [
      true,
      "ban-keywords"
    ],
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],
    "typedef": [
      true,
      "call-signature",
      "parameter",
      "member-variable-declaration"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's my tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false
  }
}
```

Comment: your IDE might use older TS version

Comment: i think that's not it, in settings > languages & frameworks > typescript, it's using the project-local version which is the latest one, 4.3.5

Comment: Show the file and and error itself (the whole IDE window if possible: sometimes small nuances (visual hints) do matter).

Comment: @LazyOne sorry but the error has disappeared now and I'm not sure what I changed. I added some `"types"` array into the tsconfig file, but I'm not sure that's the source of it. Hrmmm...